# Do I have to do the diplomatic immunity quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

No matter what I do, I can't get through it. Everyone acts like it's the easiest thing in the world but it isn't. I'm planning on restarting the game because it never saved when I wasn't in the quest but I don't want to do that quest EVER again. Do I have to do it to move on in the game?

Comment: In addition to Dragonrage's answer, I wanted to suggest that in the future, you make manual saves before starting a quest (or right after it starts). Based on the wording of your answer, it sounds like you're relying entirely on autosaves. Autosaves in Skyrim are not very reliable, and in some cases can be corrupt to the point of crashing your game if you try to load them. I know it's not a solution to your current problem, but I hope it might save you some heartache in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Diplomatic Immunity is part of the main quest line (of the main game, the Dragonborn and Dawnguard DLC's have separate quest lines), so in order to progress in the main quest line, you have to complete this quest. There are a lot of side quests and places to explore besides just doing the main quest, but Diplomatic Immunity is one of the earlier quests in the main quest line, so not completing it will prevent you from a large portion of the game.

If you are having trouble with the quest, consider following a walkthrough such as the UESP one found on [this page](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Diplomatic_Immunity) or one of the various video walkthroughs on YouTube.